# High priority gearman jobs not being treated as high priority

Tags: php, multithreading, gearman

I am implementing an "admin" hook into my gearman workers in php.  This is to monitor the overall statistics of the worker, not the job.  It would also provide a way to allow the worker to unregister, cleanup, and terminate.  I am doing this by registering a second function to handle these "admin" requests.  I figured that I could send in a "high" priority job, and that high priority job should preempt the normal priority jobs.  This does not appear to be the case.

Here is a simplified version of the test I am running:

WORKER:

```
<?php 
$gmw = new GearmanWorker();
$gmw->addServer();
$gmw->addFunction('Test', 'handleWork');
$gmw->addFunction('Admin', 'handleAdmin');
$gmw->setTimeout(10000); // 10s wait timeout for I/O activity
$pass_count = 0;
$job_count = 0;
$kill = false;
while (@$gmw->work() || $gmw->returnCode() == GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) {
    $pass_count++;
    if ($kill) {
        if ($gmw->returnCode() != GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) $gmw->unregisterAll();
        if ($gmw->returnCode() == GEARMAN_SUCCESS) $job_count++;
        print("\n\nKill command received, exiting...");
        stats(false);
        break;
    }
    if ($gmw->returnCode() == GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) {
        continue;
    } else if ($gmw->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS) {
        $gmw->unregisterAll();
        print("\n\nGot Gearman Code \"" . $gmw->returnCode() . "\", exiting");
        break;
    }
    $job_count++;
}

function handleWork(GearmanJob $job) {
    print('.');
    usleep(100000);
    return '{"consumed": true}';
}

function handleAdmin(GearmanJob $job) {
    global $kill, $pass_count, $job_count;
    $payload = json_decode($job->workload());
    if ($pass_count) $pass_count--;
    if ($job_count) $job_count--;
    switch ($payload->action) {
        case 'kill':
            $kill = true;
            return json_encode(array(
                'message' => 'Kill request received',
            ));

        case 'stats':
            return json_encode(stats(true));
    }
}

function stats($return=true) {
    global $pass_count, $job_count;
    $obj = array(
        'pass_count' => $pass_count,
        'job_count' => $job_count,
    );
    if ($return) return $obj;

    foreach ($obj as $k => $v) {
        print("\n" . $k . ":\t" . $v);
    }
    print("\n");
}
```

CLIENT 1 (sending normal work to the worker)

```
<?php
$gmc = new GearmanClient();
$gmc->addServer();

while (true) {
    print('.');
    for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
        $gmc->addTaskBackground('Test', '{"foo":"bar"}');
    }
    $gmc->runTasks();
    sleep(15);
}
```

CLIENT 2 (sending request to get stats)

```
<?php
$gmc = new GearmanClient();
$gmc->addServer();
$gmc->setCompleteCallback('output');
$gmc->addTaskHigh('Admin', '{"action":"stats"}');
$gmc->runTasks();

function output(GearmanTask $task) {
    foreach (json_decode($task->data()) as $k => $v) {
        print("\n$k:\t$v");
    }
    print("\n");
}
```

CLIENT 3 (sending request to kill worker)

```
<?php
$gmc = new GearmanClient();
$gmc->addServer();
$gmc->setCompleteCallback('output');
$gmc->addTaskHigh('Admin', '{"action":"kill"}');
$gmc->runTasks();

function output(GearmanTask $task) {
    foreach (json_decode($task->data()) as $k => $v) {
        print("\n$k:\t$v");
    }
    print("\n");
}
```

Am I going about this wrong?  Is there a better way to do this?  Note that running the WORKER and CLIENT 1 is an infinite loop.  When I run CLIENT 2 or CLIENT 3, it always waits until the previous 100 jobs sent in by CLIENT 1 to complete before running the job submitted.

Comment: I think it's because gearman won't send any task (regardless of priority) to a busy worker.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not interested in this anymore after 4 years, but I'll add an answer nevertheless, because the answer is quite funny.

Gearmand only orders execution of jobs by priority *per function*.
There are two ways to work around this limitation:

- Run two workers, one for "Test" and one for "Admin"
- Run a single worker, but register "Admin" *before* "Test" (!). This works because Gearmand picks new jobs first by function, and then by priority.

See also https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/issues/173

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to solve your setup.  Use a task supervisor like supervisord to operate multiple gearmand workers, and then you can engineer a nice way to have multiple workers respect the priorities you assign, while supervisord ensures that you have the necessary count of workers running.

Robust, works.  Am using this type of logic to spin up and spin down AMIs to transcode videos that app servers request of the workers.

Good luck!

http://supervisord.org

Comment: I plan to use Supervisord, but it doesn't handle this piece, unless I am understanding it wrong.  Does Supervisord gracefully kill workers, or track how many jobs have been processed by a given worker?

Comment: Supervisor ensures that processes are up and running, so what you do is configure it to keep workers available. With gearman you need workers to complete your tasks. Your workers run all the time, and only truly work when tasks are queued.